# Как получить id и max(timestamp)

Tags: sql, postgresql

### [image]

Получаю ее запросом :

---

`

```
select
    t.ticket_no,
    v.arrival_city,
    v.departure_city,
    v.scheduled_departure
from
    ( select ticket_no, flight_id from ticket_flights tf where ticket_no in 
        (select ticket_no from ticket_flights tf group by ticket_no having count(flight_id) > 1)) t
join (
    select
        flight_id,
        flight_no,
        arrival_city,
        departure_city,
        scheduled_departure
    from
        flights_v)v on
    t.flight_id = v.flight_id
```

`

---

Хочу из этой таблицы достать все уникальные ticket_no и максимальное scheduled_departure

делаю запрос:

---

```
`select 
ticket_no, 
arrival_city, 
departure_city, 
max(scheduled_departure) from моя_таблица
group by ticket_no, arrival_city, departure_city
```

`

Запрос выдает точно, такую же таблицу как и выше. Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно сделать. По факту хочу схватить все ticket_no с максимальным scheduler_daparture для конкретного ticket_no.

Answer (score 0):

В вашей задаче вы хотите получать информацию по паре `ticket_no`, `scheduler_daparture`, но по факту группируете по большему числу полей. Поля `arrival_city`, `departure_city` в связки `ticket_no` достаточно уникальны, поэтому вы как будто получаете туже таблицу, просто не почему группировать.

Необходимо сначала найти все требуемые уникальные пары, а потом по ним отобрать конкретные записи в первоначальной таблице.

```
select
  *
from моя_таблица t
where (t.ticket_no, t.scheduled_departure) in 
  (select 
    g.ticket_no, 
    max(g.scheduled_departure)
  from моя_таблица g 
  group by g.ticket_no)
```